# Find the row you have clicked in a table

Tags: reactjs

I want to find the id of the row clicked in table.For instance I search for a book with the title 'Mastery' and there are 2 books with the same title but different authors.These books get shown in the table correctly. What I want to do is when I click on a particular book in the table it should open up a modal with the book details in input boxes, however when I click on any of the books the modal pops up with just the details of one of the books.

*When I type in the search term ('Mastery') I get two suggestions which is the expected behaviour.* 
[image]

*When I click on the suggested search term('Mastery') and hit enter or search button. All the books with that title('Mastery') gets populated in the Table. Also the expected behaviour.*
[image]

*Now when I click on the first instance of a book with title 'Mastery' this is what I get in my modal.*
[image]

*When I click on the second instance. I get this.*
[image]

You realise that it is the same book that gets shown in the modal.

**Expected Behaviour:**
I want to be able to click on a book in the table and the book in that row get shown in the modal.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Update.css';
// import Pace from 'react-pace-progress';

//CHILD COMPONENTS
import Search from '../../Search/Search';
import Modal from './Modal/Modal';

const Table = ({ data, openBookDetails }) => (
    <table className="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr className="table-primary">
                <th scope="col">Title</th>
                <th scope="col">Author</th>
                <th scope="col">ISBN</th>
                <th scope="col">No. Of Copies</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {data.map(row => 
                <TableRow key={row._id} row={row} openBookDetails={openBookDetails}/>
            )}
            {/* Remove key={row.id} inside TableRow because it is not used to set the data in the table */}
        </tbody>
    </table>
)

const TableRow = ({ row, openBookDetails }) => (
     <tr className="table-light" onClick={openBookDetails}>
        <th scope="row" >{row.title}</th>
        <td >{row.author}</td>
        <td >{row.isbn}</td>
        <td >24</td>
    </tr>
)


class Update extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            value: '',
            suggestions: [],
            setOfAllBooks: [],
            searchedBooks: [],
            isBookDetailsOpen: false,
            searchForEmpty: true,
            isDataFetching: true,

            title: '',
            author: '',
            isbn: ''
        };
    }

    setTableData = (searchedBook) => {
        this.setState({searchedBooks: searchedBook});
    }

    openBookDetails = () => {
        this.setState({ isBookDetailsOpen: true});

        console.log(this.state.searchedBooks);

        this.setState({ title: this.state.searchedBooks.title});
        this.setState({ author: this.state.searchedBooks.author});
        this.setState({ isbn: this.state.searchedBooks.isbn});
    }

    closeBookDetails = () => {
        this.setState({ isBookDetailsOpen: false});
    }

    changeIsSearchForEmpty = () => {
        this.setState({ searchForEmpty: !this.state.searchForEmpty });
    }

    changeIsDataFetching = () => {
        this.setState({isDataFetching: !this.state.isDataFetching})
    }

    render(){

        const showHideAlert = this.state.searchForEmpty ? 'alert alert-danger d-none' : 'alert alert-danger d-block';
        // const showHideProgress1 = this.state.isDataFetching ? 'progress' : 'progress display-none';
        const showHideProgress =  this.state.isDataFetching ? 'progress progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-success progress-bar-animated d-block' : 'progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated d-none';

        const style= {
            width: "100%",
            height: "8px"
        }

        return(
            <div>
                {/* Uninstall react-pace-progress if not going to be used */}
                {/* {this.state.isDataFetching ? <Pace color="#27ae60" height="0.5px"/> : null} */}
                <div style={style}>
                    <div class={showHideProgress} role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style={style}></div>
                </div>
                <div className={showHideAlert}>
                    <strong>Sorry!</strong> You have to type in a search word/phrase.
                </div>

                <div className='px-3 pt-3'>      


                    <Search 
                        state={this.state} 
                        setTableData={this.setTableData} 
                        changeIsSearchForEmpty={this.changeIsSearchForEmpty}
                        changeIsDataFetching={this.changeIsDataFetching} />
                    <Table 
                        data={this.state.searchedBooks} 
                        openBookDetails={this.openBookDetails} />
                    <Modal 
                        data={this.state.searchedBooks} 
                        isBookDetailsOpen={this.state.isBookDetailsOpen} 
                        closeBookDetails={this.closeBookDetails}
                        updateBookDetails={this.updateBookDetails} 
                        grabTitle={this.grabTitle}
                        grabAuthor={this.grabAuthor}
                        grabISBN={this.grabISBN}
                        state={this.state} />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Update;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need some kind of ID or index on the `tr` element o your `TableRow` component. You can accomplish your goal without adding any extra react elements to your code, but your `onClick` function callback must be able to get the actual value.

If you take a look at the code below:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const data = [
  { id: "one", firstname: "john", lastname: "smith" },
  { id: "foo", firstname: "peter", lastname: "parker" }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      clicked_id: null
    };
  }

  onClick = event => {
    const id = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-rowid");
    console.log(id);
    this.setState({ clicked_id: id });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Clicked ID: {this.state.clicked_id}</div>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {data.map(e => (
              <tr key={e.id} data-rowid={e.id} onClick={this.onClick}>
                <td>{e.id}</td>
                <td>{e.firstname}</td>
                <td>{e.lastname}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

you can see that the `tr` actually has a `data-rowid` element that is later used by the `onClick` method to extract the value. You can use other tags, I just chose that one for myself.

Edit to add:

If you want to take a look at the code above working, check out this codesandbox link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/4368l97lqx

Second edit:

You could just refactor your `TableRow` component to call the `openBookDetails` prop function with the parameter that you want:

```
class TableRow extends React.Component {
  handleClick = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    const { row, openBookDetails } = this.props;
    openBookDetails(row._id);
  };

  render() {
    const { row } = this.props;
    return (
       <tr className="table-light" onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <th scope="row">{row.title}</th>
        <td>{row.author}</td>
        <td>{row.isbn}</td>
        <td>24</td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your code highlighted below:

```
<tbody>
            {data.map(row => 
                <TableRow key={row._id} row={row} openBookDetails={openBookDetails}/>
            )}
            {/* Remove key={row.id} inside TableRow because it is not used to set the data in the table */}
</tbody>
```

I think you need to pass the row values to openBookDetails like:

```
<TableRow key={row._id} row={row} openBookDetails={openBookDetails(row)}/>
```

and accordingly use the row values sent inside the openBookDetails function

Comment: Error when I do this. Maximum update depth exceeded error.

Comment: sorry.. my bad.. can you try this: 
Inside your TableRow function: 
<tr className="table-light" onClick={openBookDetails(row)}>

Comment: The way you're saying, it will trigger the `openBookDetails` function every time the `tr` element is rendered. You'd need to do `<tr className="table-light" onClick={() => openBookDetails(row)}>` (note that the `onClick` prop is a function declaration now). I don't encourage doing it like that because every time the element renders, a new function will be created and the last one will have to be 'cleaned up' by the garbage collector -- which is not a big deal with a few columns, but it might be if your table is really big.

Comment: @SergioMoura So that's the reason we bind the functions isn't it :) I was just trying to make his code work

Comment: @SergioMoura It happened to work. Thinking about scalability It will be good to solve that issue now.

Comment: Well... you bind functions to be able to use “this” when the function is called from outside of the scope of the class... you create functions outside of render function to avoid repetitive creation of functions and don’t change props of child components needlessly. If it’s not clear, let me know and I can elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrote a similar code like this

`

```
                <TableBody>
                    {rows.map((row, index) => (
                        <TableRow key={row.id} style={{
                            backgroundColor: deletingId == row.id ? 'salmon' : '',
                            color: deletingId == row.id ? 'white' : '',
                        }}>
                            <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                                {index + 1}
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">{row.stockName}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">{row.stockCount}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell
                                align="right">{row.categoryResponseDTOS.length > 0 ? row.categoryResponseDTOS.map(category => {
                                return category.categoryName + ", "
                            }) : "---"}  </TableCell>
                            <TableCell>
                                <ButtonGroup variant="contained" aria-label="outlined primary button group">
                                    <Button color="warning" id={row.id}><EditIcon/> EDIT</Button>
                                    <Button color="error" id={row.id} onClick={(e) => handleDelete(e)}>
                                        <DeleteIcon/> DELETE</Button>
                                    <Button color="success"> <ZoomInSharpIcon/> DETAIL</Button>
                                </ButtonGroup>


                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    ))}
                </TableBody>
```

`

if you have a key you check the state you created if equals to it