# want to retrieve the value of specific row in which button was clicked. but i am getting the last one

Tags: reactjs

I have table so I want to retrieve key/value of specific row in which button was clicked.

```
componentDidMount() {
    let com = this;
    firebase
        .database()
        .ref()
        .child("bills")
        .once("value", snap => {
            let items = [];
            snap.forEach(childD => {
                items.push({
                    balance: childD.val().balance,
                    bill_num: childD.val().bill_num,
                    date: childD.val().date,
                    key: childD.val().key,
                    name: childD.val().name,
                    total: childD.val().total
                });
            });
            Array.prototype.push.apply(com.state.products, items);
            com.setState({
                products: com.state.products
            });
        });
}

open = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("kal" + this.state.value);
};
handleChange=event=>{
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

render() {
    return (
                    <table className="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Bill number</th>
                                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                                <th scope="col">Date</th>
                                <th scope="col">Total</th>
                                <th scope="col">Balance</th>
                                <th scope="col">Delete</th>
                                <th scope="col">Open bill</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {console.log(this.state.products)}
                            {this.state.products.map((value, key) => (
                                <tr key={value.key}>
                                    <th scope="row">{value.bill_num}</th>
                                    <td>{value.name}</td>
                                    <td>{value.date}</td>
                                    <td>{value.total}</td>
                                    <td>{value.balance}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <form onSubmit={this.returnOrder}>
                                            <input value={value.key} type="hidden" />
                                            <button className="btn btn-danger" type="submit">
                                                Return
                                            </button>
                                        </form>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <form onSubmit={this.open}>
                                        <input value={value.key} onChange={this.handleChange} ref={ eKey => (this.inputeKey = eKey)} />

                                        <button className="btn btn-info" type="submit">
                                            Open
                                        </button>
                                        </form>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            ))}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            ) : (
                <Printout
                    keya={{
                        key: this.props.keyas
                    }}
                />
            )}
    );
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the row you have clicked in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52839437/find-the-row-you-have-clicked-in-a-table)

Answer (score 0):

Typically, tables in React are made from several components: whole table, row and for example buttons in row. So in table you place array of rows. Each row has it's child buttons. So you can send props to RowButtons child with information about clicked row.

Comment: can you please share how to find row  i am stucke with that